# Mysql sort by the word that comes after the first space on the field

Tags: mysql

I've had a request from a customer that I do not know how to handle.
Theres a query on a system that he uses that selects from a certain table/field a string comprised of a code (STBM) a blank space and a city name. The code is always 4 charachters within parentheses but the city name varies, sometimes it is comprised of two or more names

He wants the data to be listed in ascending alphabetical order, disregarding the code that preceeds the city name. Can anybody help me change the query to achieve whats is necessary to make the query more practical?

Here is the entire code:

```
<select class="cidade" name="IdDestino" id="IdDestino"  title="Requerido">
                    <option>Selecione uma Cidade <%="SELECT IdCidade,Nome FROM cidades WHERE UF='"&Formulario("UFDestino")&"'" %></option>
                    <%Set ro=Con.Execute("SELECT IdCidade,Nome FROM cidades WHERE UF='"&Formulario("UFDestino")&"'")
                While Not ro.Eof
                %>
                    <option <%=IIF(trim(ro("IdCidade"))=trim(Formulario("IdDestino"))," selected=""selected"" ","")%> value="<%=ro("IdCidade")%>"><%=ro("Nome")%></option>
                <%
                ro.MoveNext
                Wend
                %>
                </select>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow has an [edit] option, please use it... (in stead of using the comment)

Comment: Very bad way of asking question. Please show us at least a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Something like SUBSTR should help

Comment: Thank you Luuk and Asgar for the tips. I think I got it right this time.